# iterating through 2-d array in VB.Net

Tags: .net, arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration

I was amazed (and horrified) that the following code works in Vb.Net

```
Dim test2DArr As String(,) = {{"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}}

For Each s As String In test2DArr
  MsgBox(s)
Next
```

When run, four message boxes pop up showing "A", "B", "C", and then "D".

In other words, it has exactly the same behavior as:

```
Dim test1DArr As String() = {"A", "B", "C", "D"}

For Each s As String In test1DArr
  MsgBox(s)
Next
```

Can someone explain this "Feature" ?  I need to impose some structure here that is apparently not supported.  The first code example above *should* be:

```
Dim test2DArr As String(,) = {{"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}}

For Each arr As String(,) In test2DArr
  MsgBox(arr(0) & ", " & arr(1))
Next
```

and should produce two message boxes: "A, B" and "C, D", but the compiler insists that iterating through a 2-d array yields a sequence of strings, not a sequence of arrays of strings.

Am I doing something wrong or is .Net's implementation of 2-D arrays really that flimsy?

Comment: +1 This is absolutely fascinating to me.  I set [this situation up here](http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=SSBCAH17268) if other readers want to experience it for themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is .Net's implementation of 2-D arrays really that flimsy?

Yes. Multi-dimensional arrays were never really supported in .NET. I’m not sure why they exist at all (as opposed to arrays-of-arrays, i.e. jagged arrays: `String()()`). In any case, all the support is tailored to the special case of one-dimensional arrays. The framework type for arrays is always the same, regardless of dimensionality, and the interface implementation (in this case of `IEnumerable(Of T)`) is tailored to this common use case.

This means that the type of the array is always an “array of strings”, and thus it always implements the interface `IEnumerable(Of String)`. This explains why your second code *cannot* work: in order for it to work, the type of the array would have to be different.

Comment: Wow. That is supremely lame. Your answer, on the other hand, was great. Thank you, and thanks also for hipping me to jagged arrays, which I had never done in .Net. They provide an uglier, but still useful solution to this problem.